# Create table with test data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible with T-SQL to create a table with values just for testing?

```
create table Values (
  Id int identity not null,
  Minimum int not null,
  Maximum int not null
)
```

I would like to create such a table with values but not inserting in the database.

After this code I would just use it in the rest of my T-SQL code.

Comment: Yes either temp tables or table variables. Look them up in BOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with Table Variables.

```
DECLARE @Values AS TABLE
(
  Id int identity not null,
  Minimum int not null,
  Maximum int not null
)
```

and then reference them as such:

```
INSERT INTO @Values VALUES(10,20)

SELECT * FROM @Values
```